# Selecting total results on a report

Tags: reporting-services

I have a matrix with several columns and rows. Example the rows are made up of names for a company and along the top are total sales, total calls, etc.  So each row will have a number under each column, and at the bottom of each column is a total for each column.  Currently i have the report set up that if you click on any of the numbers it pulls up a detailed report for those particular items. But if you select the total number it brings up the results for the first row's column. Is there a way to make it return all the items details when you click the total number for that column instead of what ever the detail would be for the first row of that column?  Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the inscope function to check whether you are in the value or total row. If you are not in scope then pass the correct parameter to the details report.

Comment: i've never used th inscope is that part of the dataset or the report paramaters?

Comment: Actually you use it as part of a report expression. You can test it out as an output in the matrix. Once you get that working, you can build a conditional expression to determine what to pass to your detail report